# Delete image from pdf with PDFSharp

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I am using pdfsharp to draw rectangles in a pdf. After that process I want to delete specific rectangles. There is any way to achieve this?

I am using drawRectangle function.

```
gfx.DrawRectangle(XBrushes.Black, 130, 0, 100, 60);
```

I guess there is not direct way to do this...maybe I have to find the object in the dictionary of graphics but how can I obtain the Id of the rectangles(graphics)?

Comment: Do you want to delete rectangles? Why draw them first if you want to delete them later? Or do you want to delete images?

Comment: hello! actually I want to draw it and save the document, after another user can delete any rectagle or add new ones. I am using xml files to save extra data from the objects...but until now I can't figure out how to do this.